# An internet story about an immortal soldier

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

I'm looking for a short story I once read on the internet. I don't know if it was published, it looked more like a creepypasta. It was about a soldier in the medieval era who committed both bad and good deeds throughout his life. Because of this, when he died his soul was claimed by an angel and a demon. But then an entity who is said to be older than God and the Devil appears, resurrects him, and makes him immortal. I think the story ends with him been used as some kind of soldier by this entity, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How long ago did you read this? Any idea where?

Comment: Hi, and thank you. I think I read it a few years back. Maybe five at most. As to where, unfortunately, I don't remember. Now that I think about it, I believe the story was presented as a true legend and not a mere piece of fiction, but I could be wrong.